# C++ - Multiplying / adding, two integers, then determining if they are even or odd

Tags: c++, integer, multiplication, addition

I'm having trouble with a simple program which will multiply 2 integers and print the output determining if it is even or odd. It also will add the 2 integers input in the beginning and do the same on the following line. The multiplying works fine and displays if the product is even or odd properly. However, the addition is not doing so and I am not understanding why. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    int a, b;
    cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Please enter another integer: ";
    cin >> b;

    if (a*b %2== 0){
        cout << "The product of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << (a*b)
                                                       << " and is even." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The product of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << (a*b)
                                                        << " and is odd." << endl;
    };

    if (a+b %2== 0){
        cout << "The sum of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << (a+b)
                                                        << " and is even." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The sum of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << (a+b)
                                                        << " and is odd." << endl;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Any help and an explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try to avoid posting code which scrolls horizontally.  It's much harder to read.  Having done so, the line `cout << "The product of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << (a*b)` could usefully appear before the first `if` (and then you would have to output the rest to `cout`).

Comment: Spacing does not count for operator precedence!  If you are not sure of operator precedence, just use parentheses to be sure!

Answer (score 7):

[Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Basically, `%` is dealt with before `+`, so your test:

```
if (a+b % 2 == 0)
```

works out like

```
if (a + (b%2) == 0)
```

which doesn't make a whole lot of sense, and is rarely going to be true, unless both `b` is even *and* `a` is `0`.

All the operations that are to do with multiplication (`*`, `/`, `%`) have the same precedence, and are handled from left-to-right, so

```
if (a*b % 2 == 0)
```

works out ok, as:

```
if ((a*b) % 2 == 0)
```

which happens to be what you really meant.

However, these multiplication operations are handled *before* the operations related to addition (`+`, `-`). So `%` is grouped before `+`, causing your specific problem.

You may have learnt about order of operations in school, for instance I was taught [BODMAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics). Same rules apply in C++.

Personally, I find it's best to use parentheses liberally in any sort of compound expression, even when it's not strictly necessary. It can make the code a lot easier to read, rather than trying to remember all the rules in your head. So I would prefer:

```
if ((a*b) % 2 == 0) // ...
if ((a+b) % 2 == 0) // ...
```

even though the extra parentheses in the first aren't really required.

Answer (score 3):

[Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) says that `%` comes before `+` so

```
a+b %2== 0
```

Is actually

```
a + (b % 2) == 0
```

You need to wrap the addition with `()`

```
(a + b) % 2 == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly Order of Operations.

To ensure that your code is behaving the way you intend, you may wish to rewrite it like this:

```
if (((a*b) %2)== 0){
cout << "The product of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << (a*b) << " and is even." << endl;
}
else {
cout << "The product of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << (a*b) << " and is odd." << endl;
};

if (((a+b) %2)== 0){
cout << "The sum of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << (a+b) << " and is even." << endl;
}
else {
cout << "The sum of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << (a+b) << " and is odd." << endl;
}
```

You can then incrementally remove parenthesis until you're confident that the code is readable but still correct.